# How can i get a image resource from an URL

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso

I tried using the library "**Picasso**" but it needs a pre-created ImageView, and I am trying to put it in a new ImageView but when I put the id that the ImageView will have it gives me an error.

I am using this code to create the ImageView:

```
    val photo  = ImageView(applicationContext)

    photo.id = variable1
              
    Scroll.addView(photo)
```

And I am using this code to put the image:

```
Picasso.get().load("$url").into(variable1)
```

And this does not work, so I thought it will be a good idea to put the photo in a pre-created ImageView and then getting the image reference of that ImageView and giving it to the new ImageView as:

```
var photoResource = R.id.borramePerro.getResource()
photo.setImageResource(photoResource)
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

```
    class InicioSesionGoogle: AppCompatActivity() {
    
    
       override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         setContentView(R.layout.google)}

        
       var urlImagen : String

       var variable1 = 1
       fun showPhoto(url: String){
            val photo  = ImageView(applicationContext)
            
            Picasso.get().load("$url").into(variable1)

            photo.id = variable1
            
            Scroll.addView(photo)




            
            println("Photo set :D   $url with the id of: $variable1")
            variable1++

           
        }
```

**Xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="visible">

    

    

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollVieww"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="204dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>

    
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/borramePerro"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: please show the full code in activity

Comment: couldn't see setcontentview(). do put full activity and layout

Comment: plz try by changing linear layout height to  android:layout_height="wrap_content". i am not sure it works please try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's preferable to use `View.generateViewId()` to generate id for your views, small numbers might already be occupied by R.

```
photo.id = View.generateViewId()
```

You don't need id at all to use Picasso though, just do:

```
val photo = ImageView(context)
Picasso.get().load(url).into(photo)
```

Since you are using Kotlin, you might want to take a look in Coil. It's more Kotlin-friendly than Picasso. Also, notice that `"$url"` is useless and probably extra work for the CPU (insignificant of course).